# jQuery div autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for advice on how to create an autoscrolling effect using jQuery which would enable an entire div within a page to begin scrolling vertically upon loading at a constant slow speed.  This would be a div with a large amount of content of which only a small amount was visible on the screen at any one time.

The scroll needs to be automatic, smooth and at a defined rate for example 10 pixels per second.  Additionally when the scroll gets to the bottom of the page I need to be able to call a function.

I have tried a few different jQuery plugins but found nothing yet that worked reliably.  Can anybody suggest an approach to take here?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 10):

This can easily be done without jquery.

```
function init() {

    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    // increase the scroll position by 10 px every 10th of a second
    setInterval(function() { 
        // make sure it's not at the bottom
        if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
            div.scrollTop += 10; // move down
    }, 100); // 100 milliseconds

}
```

Comment: Not enough jQuery :(
[Example](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Hk1mt-RKYLc/UOkxShm6NrI/AAAAAAAACqo/LVmqHOfWV7g/s1600/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: Why suffer the performance hit of an extra library when the task is simple in native JS? This code should work in any modern browser as well as IE6+ and Firefox 2.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this technique](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12)

Answer (score 1):

try this plugin : [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

especially the onAfter