# Scroll the content at set intervals?

Tags: jquery

There are two lines as the following:

```
<div id="test"> test one jquery is a good library.<br/>
test two php is a good language.</div>
```

now i want to scroll them one by one (**the top line hide the bottom line show.vice versa**)and the line shows and hides automatically which time interval is 500  milliseconds . the scroll direction  is from bottom to top.

i don't know how to do.

the following is my code. but  I am totally stucked. i don't know how to write the function.

```
$(function(){
            $('#test').slideUp('500' function(){
        //how to write
      });
        })​
```

Comment: what is scroll them one by one? Is this what you meant? http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291645/jquery-div-autoscroll this is similar post dont use slideup that will not serve the purpose

Comment: @xiaoyi the top line hide the bottom line show, vice versa

Answer (score 1):

To switch the content you need to swap the text in the div and you need some way to repeat this after defined intervals which can be achieved by setInterval method by javascript. 
[Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSK2S/2/)

```
div1= document.getElementById('test');    

interval = setInterval(function myfun(){ 
    arr = div1.innerHTML.split(/<br[^>]*>/gi);
    div1.innerHTML = arr[1] + '<br/>' + arr[0];
  //alert(div1.innerHTML);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i am sorry, the effect shows on the JsFiddle is not i want. i want the content to scroll one by one   (the top line hide the bottom line show.they scroll with  repeatly)

Comment: I have modified my answer and demo I hope this is what you require.

Comment: your code is gorgeous, i add some css that makes the effect which i want to. but i don't know what's your code meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This can be archived by using some CSS3 animation, and a few lines of JS code.
demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Vm2wz/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/* Effect Rules */
.animated { /* you can add moz support as well */
  -webkit-transition-properties: top opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s; 
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
.top {
  top: -30px;
}
.bottom {
  top: 30px;
}

/* Canvas Setup Rules */
ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>CSS3 is so amazing.</li>
  <li>DOM is best toy.</li>
  <li>jQuery sucks every way.</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var items = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++)
  items[i].className = 'bottom hide';

var curid = 0, nextid = 1, state = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  switch (state) {
    case 0: // hide items[curid], and show items[nextid] in 250ms
      items[curid].className = 'animated top hide';
      items[nextid].className = 'animated';
      state = 1;
    break;
    case 1: // move items[curid] to bottom, curid = nextid, nextid++;
      items[curid].className = 'bottom hide';
      curid = nextid;
      if (++nextid >= items.length) nextid = 0;
      state = 0;
    break;
  } // you may also add a state 2 which do nothing but wait 250ms. then the state goes from 0 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0.
}, 250);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, i want to the code run on IE7 how should i do? want to make a friend with you. my qq is 285967378  :(